# Angular msal_angular with ASP.NET Core Web API returns invalid token invalid signature AzureAD

Tags: angular, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-webapi, azure-ad-msal, bearer-token

I built an Angular application following this example: 
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-angularspa

I'm able to login and even authenticate to MS Graph from the Angular app.

I'm trying to pass the token to an API service that I have created as well. However I keep getting the below error:

> WWW-Authenticate: Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="The signature is invalid"

I've tried everything possible so far was no luck. I continue to get this error. I've tried the `AzureADBearer` library:

```
services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.BearerAuthenticationScheme)
    .AddAzureADBearer(options => Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

services.Configure<JwtBearerOptions>(AzureADDefaults.JwtBearerAuthenticationScheme, options => 
{
    options.Authority += "/v2.0";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudiences = new string[]
    {
        options.Audience, $"api://{options.Audience}"
    };

    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateIssuer = false;
    options.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerValidator = AadIssuerValidator.GetIssuerValidator(options.Authority).Validate;
});
```

I've also tried the `Microsoft.Identity.Web` library but I'm getting the same error:

```
services.AddProtectedWebApi(Configuration);
```

I've been searching for few days now, I've found others with the same problem but so far no clear solution. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT**

I'm trying to build an application for my organization that uses our AzureAD for authentication. The application has Angular frontend with aspnetcore webapi as backend. I'm not too particular on how to get this achieved. Just looking for away to get it done.

Comment: How does the token you are sending look like? It is possible your API in AAD is configured to get v1 tokens. In that case the signing keys might be different. You can tell if it is a v1 token by looking at the issuer claim (iss); v1 tokens have `https://sts.windows.net/guid`. You can inspect the token at e.g. https://jwt.ms.

Comment: It's a v1 token. Although my endpoint is pointing to v2 and app manifest is set to return v2 tokens, the token that I'm receiving is v1.

Comment: Okay, that's odd  How are you acquiring the token? What are you using as the scope?

Comment: these are the scopes I'm using
`scopes: [
    'user.read',
    'calendars.read',
    'api://[Api id]/access_as_user',
    'openid',
    'profile'
  ]`

Comment: Okay, the audience in the token your API is receiving should match the API client id or app id URI. Otherwise you may be sending a MS Graph API token to your API, which is not correct.

Comment: This is the code to initialize MsalModule:
`MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: OAuthSettings.appId,
      authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}',
    })
  ],`

Comment: Use https://jwt.ms/ to decode the access token and check what is the audience

Comment: @NanYu the aud is MS GraphAPI. But I couldn't find away to set the aud to my app id in msal_angular

Comment: check [this](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angularjs#7-get-tokens-for-web-api-calls) for how to get tokens for api call , and refer to code sample [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/tree/dev/lib/msal-angularjs/tests/sample) .

Comment: @NanYu thank you that led me to the answer

Comment: @juunas thank you your respond on another post has also helped me find the answer

Comment: @spider913 Since your issue has been resolved, could you please post your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some assistance from Junnas and NanYu and few old posts, I figured out the issue. In my previous setup I had the scopes for my Api and MS Graph together, but the problem is that the token returned for each is different. I needed to acquire different tokens when reaching the different Api (mine vs Graph). After splitting the scopes and acquiring the token independently, I was able to authenticate with both. Also the `MsalInterceptor` work very well if setup correctly and saves me from writing separate calls to acquire the tokens. Here's my code:

**oauth.ts**

```
export const OAuthSettings = {
    appId: '{client Id}',
    authority: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant Id}',
    apiScopes: [
        'api://{api id}/access_as_user'
    ],
    graphScopes: [
        'user.read'
    ]
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MsalModule, MsalInterceptor } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { LogLevel } from 'msal';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { OAuthSettings } from '../oauth';

// this is only for logging and tracing
export function msalLogCallBack(level: LogLevel, message: string, containsPii: boolean) {
  console.log('[MSAL]:' + message);
}

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MsalModule.forRoot({
      clientID: OAuthSettings.appId,
      authority: OAuthSettings.authority,
      unprotectedResources: ['{angular app uri}'],
      protectedResourceMap: [
        ['{api endpoint}', OAuthSettings.apiScopes],
        ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', OAuthSettings.graphScopes]
      ],
      level: LogLevel.Verbose,
      logger: msalLogCallBack
    })
  ],
  providers: [ {
    provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
    useClass: MsalInterceptor,
    multi: true
}],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

From this point any calls made to the Api will be intercepted and the correct token will be attached in the header of the call by the `MsalInterceptor`.

Comment: Hello @spider913 I followed your solution but I still getting errors. So, did you change something to your Startup.cs of your API? You still use v2 of Authority? Also I'm getting error to AadIssuerValidator. I'm using dotnetcore 3.1